# Creating a new stage in Adobe Edge Preview 0.10.0.134.17040

Tags: css, animation

I recently started working with Adobe Edge, and need to create an additional stage for a more complex animation. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one stage per document with Edge, just as with Flash or AE. You can build animations as symbols with their own *timelines* inside the stage, though, just as you can with Flash movieclips. That should get you where you need to go.

[This video](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adobe-edge-preview/introducing-edge-preview-6/) by Mark Anders covers symbols, starting about 5m 10s.